# Clearing ListView

Tags: android, adapter

this is my adapter code

```
 package com.example.dovizkuru;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Doviz>     dovizListesi;


   public Adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Doviz> list) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        dovizListesi = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dovizListesi.size();
        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View satirView;

        satirView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        TextView textView = 
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.textView1); 
        TextView textView1 = 
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
        TextView textView2 = 
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView textView3 = 
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
        TextView textView4 = 
                (TextView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.textView5); 
        ImageView imageView = 
                (ImageView) satirView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        textView.setText("Satış fiyati");
        textView1.setText("Alış fiyati");
        textView2.setText(dovizListesi.get(position).getAlis());
        textView3.setText(dovizListesi.get(position).getSatis());
        textView4.setText(dovizListesi.get(position).getAdi());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo);


        return satirView;

 }
}
```

the problem is whenever i get into adapter it keeps stacking the data on top of the list like it gives 6 outputs at first but when some1 clicks the button that calls adapter again it makes the outputs 12 while it should have been stayed at 6 with just refreshed data. I tried to add clear(),and destory of my list at the end of adaptor but it ended up in an error. 
Q: What do i need to do so i can replace my ListView instead of adding new data on top.

this is where i add.
    try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                jsonArrayGold = jObj.getJSONArray("value");

```
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayGold.length(); i++) {

                Altin altin = new Altin();

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArrayGold.getJSONObject(i);
                altin.setAdi(jsonObject.getString("adi"));  
                altin.setAlis(jsonObject.getString("alis"));
                altin.setSatis(jsonObject.getString("satis"));
                altin.setKey(jsonObject.getString("key"));
                altin.setKey2(jsonObject.getString("key2"));
                altin.setType(jsonObject.getString("type"));
                altin.setUpDown(jsonObject.getString("upDown"));
                list.add(altin.getAdi());
                list.add(altin.getAlis());
                list.add(altin.getSatis());
                altinList.add(altin);

            }       
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you setting your adapter? You are probably using .add() somewhere.

Comment: call arraylist.clear() before adding data in array list.

Comment: i added the part where i did add();

Comment: and the arraylist.clear didnt work it made the app crash.

Comment: Try to call notifyDataSetChanged() in your custom adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you add new items to your list, clear the list first then add your items. then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method from the adapter.

```
altinList.clear();

for (){
    altinList.add(altin);



//adapter call
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: you mean i write the notifyer at adapter or ?

Comment: when you set adapter for listView, keep a reference for the adapter. then use it for data changes. Adapter already has this method btw.

Comment: by the way i tried the .clear method before the for() { ... } and it worked nicely should i still put notifyDataSetChanged() in adapter?

Comment: do you create a new adapter and set it to listview? If that is no need, but you can avoid creating everytime when you want to change data.

Comment: yes i do as " ListView listview =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  adapter2 = new Adapter2(this,altinList);
  listview.setAdapter(adapter2);" 
but its 1 time progress its not inside any loops or anything i think no?